# Can list.files() ignore paths which do not contain the pattern in R?

Tags: r

I want to merge data from different folders. Therefore I first make an object with all my mapnames in the current working directory (with list.dirs()). Afterwards I look in every map for specific filesnames (my pattern). 
The problem is when a file does not contain this specific string, list.files() gives an error.

```
(Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file 'NA': No such file or directory).
```

When I select only maps which I know contain the pattern, the code works.

Does anybody know how to make list.files() ignore a path that doesn't contain a certain pattern?

This is my code:

```
GS.dir<- list.dirs(path = ".",  recursive = TRUE)
ligustrum <- c()

    for (j in 1:length(GS.dir)){          
        files <- list.files(GS.dir[j], pattern = glob2rx("li*Avg.txt"), full.names = TRUE)
        if(!is.null(files)){
            for (i in 1:length(files)){
                plot <- read.table(files[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
                datum <- substr(files[i], 1, 8)
                nummer <- substr(files[i], nchar(files[i]) - 7, nchar(files[i]) - 7)
                plot.date <- data.frame("Date" = rep(datum, length(plot[,1])), 
                                        "plotnr"=rep(nummer,length(plot[,1])), 
                                         plot
                                        )
                ligustrum <- rbind(ligustrum, plot.date)
            }
        } else {
            ligustrum <- ligustrum
        }
     }

    write.table(ligustrum, "ligustrum.txt", sep = ";", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Have you investigated the specific point at which your code fails? With `for` loops, you can run them, let them fail, then check what the input values are (in your case `j` and `i`). With those inputs, run each step of your code to see where and how it's failing.

Comment: There are two ways you can handle "no string", either test for this and use an `if` function to avoid or handle it somehow, or use `tryCatch` to catch any error and handle it. This way the execution doesn't stop and the function runs further.

Answer (score 0):

`GS.dir<- list.dirs(path = ".",  recursive = TRUE)` lists all the files under the `"."`. When you call `list.files()` again, your script do a lot of unnecessary  work. For example `list.files("./mydir/subdir/subsubdir/file.txt")` will return `character(0)`. My opinion, you already got everything you need in first line of the code. Then you can just subset this vector of paths by your regexpr:

```
GS.files <- list.dirs(path = ".",  recursive = TRUE)
files <- GS.files[grepl("li*Avg.txt", GS.files)]
```

And after that it's probably easier to get the job done with `dplyr` or `data.table` instead of nested loops.

**[upd]**

```
require(dplyr)

data.frame(files = list.files(recursive = T)) %>%
        filter(grepl("li(.)*Avg.txt",files)) %>%
        mutate(files = as.character(files)) %>%
        group_by(files) %>%
        mutate(datum = substr(substr(files, 
                                     max(gregexpr("/",files)[[1]])+1, 
                                     nchar(files)
                                     ), 1, 8),
               nummer = substr(files, nchar(files) - 7, nchar(files) - 7)) %>%
        do(data.frame(datum = as.Date(.$datum, format = "%Y%m%d"),
                      nummer = as.numeric(.$nummer), 
                      read.table(.$files, T))) %>%
        arrange(datum, nummer, files) %>%
        write.table(.,file = "ligstrum.txt", sep = ";", row.names = F)
```

Comment: So instead of  'files <- list.files(GS.dir[j], pattern =glob2rx("li*Avg.txt"), full.names = TRUE)', I should use 'files <- GS.dir[grepl("li*Avg.txt"), GS.dir)]'
this unfortunatly doesn't solve the error

Comment: I will try to reproduce your example a bit latter. I lat you know if it works or not.